Why am I getting a typescript error when following the nextjs tutorial?
I'm learning nextjs with the nextjs tutorial, and I'm now implementing partial prerendering here: https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/partial-prerendering#implementing-partial-prerendering
I'm getting a typescript error in the app/dashboard/layout.tsx file saying:
"experimental_ppr" is not a valid Next.js entry export value.ts(71002)
Why is that?
ChatGPT told that the line in the layout.tsx is not correct and advised to remove it. Could it be that there's a mistake in the tutorial?

Nextjs tutorial - partial prerendering

Odd: is this error on hover or in the PROBLEMS tab in VS Code?  I am doing this tutorial right now, didn't encounter the issue.

It's both. If I hover the experimental_ppr variable, and it is also shown in the problems tab

I read the documentation about ppr and it looks like that the tutorial is correct.
PPR is first configured in the next.config.mjs, and if it's set 'incremental', you can add the export const experimental_ppr = true to the layout or page where you want to use it.
It's just a typescript issue that I can't solve. Maybe I'll get it later, when I'm wiser.

I got the same error when trying to use ppr in my new Next.js 14 project and got an error message in the console: "Error: The experimental.ppr preview feature can only be enabled when using the latest canary version of Next.js. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/ppr-preview".
So maybe you are not on the latest canary?
